# Multiply numerical value after a string in a json file by 3?

Tags: bash, awk, json

I'm trying to replace a number in a set of text files.  The number will be different for each file, but it will always occur after a specific string.

Here's the original file:

```
    "structures": [
        {
            "structure": "wabi_sabi_structures:abandoned_small_castle",
            "weight": 1
        }
    ],
    "placement": {
        "type": "random_spread",
        "spacing": 90,
        "separation": 60,
        "salt": 85683942
    }
}
```

I'd like to multiply the value after ""spacing": " by 3.  So in this case the final line would read `"spacing": 270,` .

I've tried playing around with awk, but due to the various colon's and quotation marks, I'm constantly getting errors.  How can I passthrough `"spacing":` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using `jq`

Answer (score 1):

As Jaromanda X comments, [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is the tool of choice for manipulating JSON data:

```sh
jq '.placement.spacing *= 3' file.json
```

Comment: That doesn't store the results back into the file, though that's straightforward to do.

Comment: I had no idea this was even a thing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could always just use node with JSON.parse() and reflection. I'm pretty sure the fields won't get sorted in memory, they get loaded in the order they're loaded.

And just walk through the tree.

But I do have a couple of questions.

How big is the json file ?

It sounds like you want any integer value after a string ?
Or is it just those named "spacing" ?

Is it any value after a string or only the first per object ?
Do the fields have different names ?

This will modify the answer. Let me know and I'll touch on this.